# How can I undo destroy command in ember-cli?

Tags: ember-cli

I use ember-cli. I destroyed route mistakenly:

```
ember destroy route x
```

Can I restore deleted files?

Comment: Maybe here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724634/ember-restore-state-when-routing/27726654#27726654

Comment: No, I need to recover deleted files, not route state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have the route that was destroyed committed to Git?  If you didn't, Ember doesn't provide anything that will help with that, you'd need to look into file recovery tools for your OS ...